# nodej.js handling of post req.body is not working

Tags: node.js

I spend so much time looking at this.. I am just following udemy tutorial where instructor used exactly below.. BUT when I run it, req.body is empty EVEN though I am sending it from source(I tried from both nodeman and insomnia).  I am just posting { "name":"test" }... and it's not getting the req.body... 
I console logged just req and do not see the parm 'body'... Can someone please throw me some light here? SO furstrated

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const port = 8002;

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`port : ${port}`);
})
```

Comment: What exactly you are getting? Some error or anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `body-parser` for your req.body.
First install the dependency `npm install body-parser` and then try executing the below code:

```
const app = express();
const bodyParser= require('body-parser')

const port = 8002;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`port : ${port}`);
})
```

For more documentation refer: [body-parser-documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html)

Comment: app.use(express.json());